# How can I combine values from three variables into one variable?

Tags: r, if-statement

What I'm trying to do is to create a single cataract variable from three different datasets that asked about cataract. (Basically, a phone interview, a wave using a short questionnaire, and a wave using a longer questionnaire.) These datasets have been merged, such that there are missing values created for the values for participants in the wave they didn't participate in. I've coded each of the three separate cataract vars as 1=YES and 0=NO.

In the following code, I'm trying to say if you respond yes (1) to any of the three vars, then give a value of 1, then if you are a No (0) to any give a value of 0, otherwise "NA".

```
survey$cataract<-ifelse(survey$ew3_cat==1 | survey$lq3_catnum==1 | survey$sq3_cat==1,1,
                        ifelse(survey$ew3_cat==0 | survey$lq3_catnum==0 | survey$sq3_cat==0,0,NA))
```

As you can see from the following result, I get the 1's, but everything else is "NA", no zeros.

```
> table(survey$cataract,useNA="ifany")

    1  <NA> 
10303 63322
```

Now, if I change the order, say do all the zeros first, then I get the correct 0's, but no 1's.

```
survey$cataract<-ifelse(survey$ew3_cat==0 | survey$lq3_catnum==0 | survey$sq3_cat==0,0,
                        ifelse(survey$ew3_cat==1 | survey$lq3_catnum==1 | survey$sq3_cat==1,1,NA))

> table(survey$cataract,useNA="ifany")

    0  <NA> 
63315 10310
```

The correct count from the three separate vars should be:

```
10,303 = 1
63,315 = 0
7= NA
```

I also tried replicating this problem with made-up data as follows:

```
x <- c(rep(1,100),rep(0,200),rep(NA,400))
y <- c(rep(NA,300),rep(1,100),rep(0,100),rep(NA,200))
z <- c(rep(NA,500),rep(1,100),rep(0,100))

cat <- ifelse(x==1|y==1|z==1,1,
         ifelse(x==0|y==0|z==0,0,NA))
> table(cat,useNA="ifany")
cat
   1 <NA> 
 300  400
```

Same problem if I reverse the order:

```
cat <- ifelse(x==0|y==0|z==0,0,
         ifelse(x==1|y==1|z==1,1,NA))
> table(cat,useNA="ifany")
cat
   0 <NA> 
 400  300
```

Any suggestions about what logical thing I'm missing here?

Comment: I think you need to clarify your criteria for 'cat'. If I understand you correctly, you write that if _any_ of x, y, z is 0, then you want to set 'cat' to zero. At the same time you write that if _any_ of x, y, z is 1, then you want to set 'cat' to one. So if, for example, x = 0, y = 1, z = NA, then the criteria for both cat = 0 _and_ cat = 1 is fulfilled.

Comment: Yes, sorry for the lack of clarity. So, the three separate variables are asking the same questions to different people. Therefore, the final dataset is appended together. The variable for the first survey, will have missing values for the people represented in the second and third surveys. The variable for the second survey, will have missing values for the first and third surveys, and so on. Of course, there is the possibility that all variables will have an NA, and that is when a person didn't answer the question in their wave.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a little hackish but should give you the right result:

```
tmp <- as.numeric(mapply(any, as.logical(x),as.logical(y),as.logical(z), na.rm=TRUE))
tmp[which(mapply(all, is.na(x), is.na(y), is.na(z)))] <- NA
```

Basically it looks for any values of 1, returning 1 for those values and 0 otherwise. Then it goes back and puts `NA` values back in wherever all of `x`, `y`, and `z` are `NA`.

```
> table(tmp)
tmp
  0   1 
400 300
```

Note: Your example data don't seem particularly good for testing this because you have cases that are `NA-NA-NA`:

```
> ftable(x,y,z, useNA='always')
      z   0   1  NA
x  y               
0  0      0   0   0
   1      0   0   0
   NA     0   0 200
1  0      0   0   0
   1      0   0   0
   NA     0   0 100
NA 0      0   0 100
   1      0   0 100
   NA   100 100   0
```

So, here's a slightly modified version of your data that shows the above code works correctly:

```
x <- c(rep(1,100),rep(0,200),rep(NA,400))
y <- c(rep(NA,300),rep(1,100),rep(0,100),rep(NA,200))
z <- c(rep(NA,500),rep(1,100),rep(0,50),rep(NA,50))
```

The result for those data:

```
> ftable(x,y,z, useNA='always')
      z   0   1  NA
x  y               
0  0      0   0   0
   1      0   0   0
   NA     0   0 200
1  0      0   0   0
   1      0   0   0
   NA     0   0 100
NA 0      0   0 100
   1      0   0 100
   NA    50 100  50

> table(tmp, useNA='always')
tmp
   0    1 <NA> 
 350  300   50
```

Comment: @user3314465, Because you are new on SO, please take time to read [**about Stackoverflow**](http://stackoverflow.com/about) and [**what to do when someone answers**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers).